# extract content between nested parenthesis

Tags: python, string

I want to extract between `ObjectUnionOf(` and the first closed parenthese coming after it:

`<http://www.ifomis.org/bfo/1.1/spanScatteredTemporalRegion> <http://www.ifomis.org/bfo/1.1/spanConnectedTemporalRegion>`

From

```
EquivalentClasses(<http://www.ifomis.org/bfo/1.1/spanTemporalRegion> ObjectUnionOf(<http://www.ifomis.org/bfo/1.1/spanScatteredTemporalRegion> <http://www.ifomis.org/bfo/1.1/spanConnectedTemporalRegion>))
```

I tried:

```
content=content[content.find("ObjectUnionOf(")+1:content.find(")")]
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Regex:

```
import re
s = "EquivalentClasses(<http://www.ifomis.org/bfo/1.1/spanTemporalRegion> ObjectUnionOf(<http://www.ifomis.org/bfo/1.1/spanScatteredTemporalRegion> <http://www.ifomis.org/bfo/1.1/spanConnectedTemporalRegion>))"
m = re.search("ObjectUnionOf\((?P<links>.*?)\)", s)
if m:
    print( m.group('links') )
```

**Output:**

```
<http://www.ifomis.org/bfo/1.1/spanScatteredTemporalRegion> <http://www.ifomis.org/bfo/1.1/spanConnectedTemporalRegion>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `re.findall`:

```
import re

txt = '''EquivalentClasses(<http://www.ifomis.org/bfo/1.1/spanTemporalRegion> ObjectUnionOf(<http://www.ifomis.org/bfo/1.1/spanScatteredTemporalRegion> <http://www.ifomis.org/bfo/1.1/spanConnectedTemporalRegion>))'''

print('\n'.join(re.findall(r'ObjectUnionOf\((.*)\)\)', txt)))

# <http://www.ifomis.org/bfo/1.1/spanScatteredTemporalRegion> 
# <http://www.ifomis.org/bfo/1.1/spanConnectedTemporalRegion>
```